# Create stacked area graph from time data

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I'm a social science researcher, working to visualize how people move through various roles over time in a community.

I have clustered people's monthly behavior into role categories, and now I want to visualize the number and ratio of people that are in each role at each (relative) time period.

Right now, the data is in a CSV that looks something like this:

```
ID  T1  T2  T3 ...
1   2   2   3
2   1   0   2
3   1   2   1
...
```

Where X(ij) is the cluster ID i was in during their jth month.

What I would like is something like this (which I created in LibreOffice).
[image]

I believe I will need to use ggplot2, but I have really been struggling to figure out how to get the data in a format that ggplot likes.

I guess my first task would be to summarize each cluster at each time period? Is there an easy way to do that?

I can do this with the following code, but it's terrible and messy, and there must be a better way to do it?

```
clus1 <- apply(clusters, 2, function(x) {sum(x=='1', na.rm=TRUE)})
clus2 <- apply(clusters, 2, function(x) {sum(x=='2', na.rm=TRUE)})
clus3 <- apply(clusters, 2, function(x) {sum(x=='3', na.rm=TRUE)})
clus0 <- apply(clusters, 2, function(x) {sum(x=='0', na.rm=TRUE)})
clusters2 <- data.frame(clus0, clus1, clus2, clus3)
c2 <- t(clusters2)
c3 <- as.data.frame(c2)
c3$id = c('Low Activity Cluster', 'Cluster 1', 'Cluster 2', 'Cluster 3')
c3 <- c3[order(c3$'id'),]
print(ggplot(melt(c3, id.vars="id")) +
  geom_area(aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=id, group=id), position="fill"))
```

This results in something like this for the sample data:

```
id                      T1  T2  T3
Low Activity Cluster     0   1   0
Cluster 1                2   0   1
Cluster 2                1   2   1
Cluster 3                0   0   1
```

Is that the right strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITs, trying to address comments:

```
`rownames<-`(
  as.data.frame(lapply(df[-1], function(x) as.numeric(table(x)))), 
  paste("Clust ", 0:3)
)
```

Produces:

```
         T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8 T9 T10
Clust  0  4  3  5  8 11  6  2  4  5   7
Clust  1  5  9  8  6  3  7  7  8  7   4
Clust  2  5  6  2  3  3  3  2  3  4   4
Clust  3  6  2  5  3  3  4  9  5  4   5
```

This counts the # of occurrences of each cluster type (0:3) at each time period using `table`.  The key piece of code is the `lapply(...)`.  The stuff around it is just so it displays pretty.

With data:

```
set.seed(1)
labels <- paste("Clust ", 0:3)
df <- as.data.frame(c(list(ID=1:20), setNames(replicate(10, factor(sample(0:3, 20, rep=T)), simplify=F), paste0("T", 1:10))))
```

---

Here is a `ggplot` solution.  First you need to get the data into long format with `melt` from the `reshape2` package, you can then aggregate it (optionally re-cast it), and then plot it:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df.mlt <- melt(df, id.vars="ID")
df.agg <- aggregate(. ~ ID + variable, df.mlt, sum)
dcast(df.agg, ID ~ variable)  # just for show, we don't use the result anyplace

#   ID T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8 T9 T10
# 1  0 25 18 29 23 16 15 14 22 29  19
# 2  1  7  7 14 18 19 11 21 17 15  22
# 3  2 16 15 16 20 23 20 16 13 15  12
# 4  3 14 13 20 17 25 14 13  7 21  24

ggplot(df.agg) +
  geom_area(aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=ID, group=ID), position="fill")
```

[image]

It takes a little getting used to `ggplot`, but once you do get used to it is mostly intuitive.  You should look at the result of `melt(df, id.vars="ID")` to see what I mean by "long format" first.  Then, in this case, we use `geom_area`, and specify as "aesthetics" (values that change with the data) in `aes` the `x` value (`variable` is a name produced by `melt`, in this case it contains the `time` values), the `y` value (`value` is also created by `melt`), and also specify that the color of the fill of our areas should be derived from the `ID`.  Note that because the time we're using here is categorical (T1, T2, etc., instead of actual dates), we must use `group` in addition to `fill` so that `ggplot` knows that you want points in different times to be connected.

Note you do not need to do the aggregation step ahead of plotting.  `ggplot` can handle it internally.  The following command is equivalent (note how we're using `df.mlt`):

```
ggplot(df.mlt) +
  stat_summary(aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=ID, group=ID), fun.y=sum, position="fill", geom="area")
```

This is the data I used:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(list(ID=rep(factor(0:3), 3)), setNames(replicate(10, sample(1:10, 12, rep=T), simplify=F), paste0("T", 1:10))))
```

Comment: That's really, really helpful, but I think it's the second half of the problem.

I probably wasn't clear enough about the first half. I don't want to plot how each user's roles change over time - rather, I want to plot the ratio of all roles over time. I'll adjust the original question to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but that isn't working. My df.agg has 3 columns - id, variable, and value, where the value is just the cluster for that user at that time.

I'm adding some comments to my question with some code that appears to have worked, although it's complicated code.

Comment: @Jeremy, that is normal.  Look at the next step (the `dcast`).  That converts the three column format (long format) to what you are wanting to see (wide format).  Most of R analytical tools that operate on groups (including `ggplot`) use long format data (in this case, the three column version).

Comment: I think the problem may be that I didn't explain the original data well enough. The first column (ID) represents the UserID, not the cluster ID. So, there are thousands of rows, with different IDs. My goal is to aggregate the cluster values (which is the value in the table) across IDs, for each time.


As a side note, thanks so, so much for your help!!!